# Filter by multiple conditions in TortoiseHg Workbench

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Is it possible to combine multiple conditions in filter? E.g. Find all revisions from certain author AND where was .js file modified.

I can filter revisions either by author `user('Joe')` or by file extension `file('**.js')`, but don't know how to combine these.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some Trail and Error, found it:

Combine conditions with AND:

`user('Joe') & file('**.js')`

`user('Joe') and file('**.js')`

Combine conditions with OR:

`user('Joe') | file('**.js')`

`user('Joe') or file('**.js')`

Joining conditions with `AND` and `OR` (uppercase) **will not work** (Invalid token error).

For TortoiseHg version 3.7.3